# Optimize simulations with expand.grid (and dplyr?)

Tags: r

I have this basic function 'follow_up' (which is simpler than my real function…), which extracts some information from a linear regression. The two parameters are the number of individual (n) and the number of repetitions by individual (rp).

```
follow_up <- function(n=10,rp=5){
donnees <- data.frame(Id=rep(1:n, rep(rp,n)),X=rnorm(n*rp),Y=rnorm(n*rp,4,2))
sfit <- summary(lm(Y~X, donnees))
output <- c(sfit$R.chisq,sfit$coeff[1],sfit$coeff[2])
return(output)
}
n=c(5,10)
rp=c(2,4,6)
p=expand.grid(n=n,rp=rp)
```

I would like to realize big simulations, and obtaining this following:

for each combination of n and rp (both sitting in the two first columns as it is provided by expand.grid), I would like to realize around 1,000 iterations, evaluate for each iteration the 'follow_up' function, and put in the other columns of the data frame the mean of the three components returned by 'follow_up' (i.e. means of R2 and coeffs).

Because my real function is more complicated and because n and rp are of higher dimensions, I would like to optimize my code (for example by avoiding rbind or loop if possible). Thank you for your help.

Comment: `follow_up` only returns a 2-element vector...is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
set.seed(1)
follow_up_vectorized <- Vectorize(follow_up)
sims <- replicate(1e3, follow_up_vectorized(p$n, p$rp))
res <- apply(sims, c(1, 2), mean)

#             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]         [,6]
# [1,]  4.00783364  3.991355959 4.011558264 3.983996744  3.99937381  4.009033518
# [2,] -0.03425608 -0.004379941 0.005743333 0.005036114 -0.01332833 -0.007702833
```

But I wouldn't call it "optimization" without knowing about the performance bottlenecks of your actual code.

---

**Edit**
Per CPak's request, output as new columns:

```
cbind(p, t(res))

#    n rp        1            2
# 1  5  2 4.007834 -0.034256082
# 2 10  2 3.991356 -0.004379941
# 3  5  4 4.011558  0.005743333
# 4 10  4 3.983997  0.005036114
# 5  5  6 3.999374 -0.013328326
# 6 10  6 4.009034 -0.007702833
```

Comment: "Meaningful" is in the eye of OP... and I consider the question too vague to be absolutely sure what that means myself... so unfortunately, I can't. But what do you have in mind? (Also: added output)

Comment: @CPak Edited my answer. Btw, I'm all for benchmarks, but I don't think they mean anything here. Both our solutions are very thin wrappers around the main computation and probably won't have any serious impact on performance. Optimization would probably benefit more inside `follow_up()`, but I'm afraid we can't help here, without an idea of the actual code

Answer (score 1):

#### Your data

```
n=c(5,10)
rp=c(2,4,6)
p=expand.grid(n=n,rp=rp)
```

#### Change function to return data frame

```
follow_up_df <- function(n=10,rp=5){
                  donnees <- data.frame(Id=rep(1:n, rep(rp,n)),X=rnorm(n*rp),Y=rnorm(n*rp,4,2))
                  sfit <- summary(lm(Y~X, donnees))
                  output <- c(sfit$R.chisq, sfit$coeff[1], sfit$coeff[2])
                  df <- data.frame(X1=output[1], X2=output[2])
                  return(df)
                }
```

#### tidyverse solution

```
CP <- function() {
          require(tidyverse)
          totiter <- 1000

          # Copy p 1000 times
          p1 = p[rep(seq_len(nrow(p)), totiter ), ] %>%                     
                 mutate(ID = seq_len(totiter*nrow(p)))                      # unique ID to join

          # Calculate mean of N iterations
          ans <- map_df(1:nrow(p1), ~follow_up(p1$n[.x], p1$rp[.x])) %>%    # follow_up rowwise
                    mutate(ID = seq_len(totiter*nrow(p))) %>%               # unique ID to join
                    left_join(., p1, by="ID") %>%                           # join with p1
                    group_by(n, rp) %>%     
                    summarise(X1 = mean(X1), X2 = mean(X2)) %>%             # mean per n,rp pair
                    ungroup()
      }
```

#### Output

```
set.seed(1)

      n    rp       X1           X2
1     5     2 4.007834 -0.034256082
2     5     4 4.011558  0.005743333
3     5     6 3.999374 -0.013328326
4    10     2 3.991356 -0.004379941
5    10     4 3.983997  0.005036114
6    10     6 4.009034 -0.007702833
```

#### Other solutions

```
 Aurele <- function() {
              set.seed(1)
              follow_up_vectorized <- Vectorize(follow_up)
              sims <- replicate(1e3, follow_up_vectorized(p$n, p$rp))
              res <- apply(sims, c(1, 2), mean)
          }
```

#### Performance

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(CP(), times=5L)   

    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    CP() 25.02497 25.58269 25.83376 25.92396 26.26672 26.37044     5
Aurele() 21.31826 21.44110 21.73005 21.79842 21.85301 22.23944     5
```

#### Conclusion

```
Aurele's solution is faster!
```

Comment: I would like to thank you for your responses. The Aurele solution works great.

Comment: @VarheureTimme Consider accepting Aureles answer by clicking on the *check mark* to the left of the answer. It acknowledges the contribution and lets the community know the answer worked for you.